# How to insert UTC with Time Zone in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have code in postgresql transform to sql server
In postgresql while inserting in table with data type timestamp with time zone in UTC format, it inserted with time zone

```
create table public.testt123 (tz timestamp with time zone)


insert into public.testt123
select now() at time zone 'utc'

select * from public.testt123
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyAQc.png)

I have tried same with Sql server, below query

```
create table Test1(tz [datetimeoffset](7))

insert into Test1
select GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRRBM.png)

It inserted without time zone, I have check using SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() but it gives time zone with current datetime not UTC

I have tried by left function, but it is correct way?

```
Select cast(left(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',28) + DATENAME(TZOFFSET, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) as [datetimeoffset](7))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj2VZ.png)

Comment: *"It inserted without time zone,"* `GETUTCDATE` and `GETDATE()` return a `datetime`, not a `datetimeoffset`, however, you are *inserting* into a `datetimeoffset` so the value stored will *always* have a offset time. The [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRRBM.png) you provide appears to be correct, so i don't see the problem...

Comment: @Larnu, I have inserted with GETUTCDATE but getting time zone +00:00, i was looking for UTC with time zone +05:30

Comment: Then that **isn't** UTC... UTC is +00:00

Comment: @Larnu,thanks, why in postgresql show "2022-12-02 13:02:48.941689+05:30", it should be "2022-12-02 13:33:33.8176409 +00:00" correct?

Comment: This question is about SQL Server, not PostgreSQL; if you're asking about PostgreSQL, you've used the wrong tags.

Comment: @Rchoudhary SQL Server and PostgreSQL are completely different database products. You can't use one database's types an functions in another

Comment: In any case neither PostgreSQL nor SQL Server are broken. Their offset-aware types store what you send to them. If you tell them to store UTC, ie `+00:00`, that's what they'll store. UTC is a specific offset, not a format. If you try to "fix" `datatetimeoffset` or `tz timestamp with time zone` you'll only end up storing the wrong time

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, I suspect what you want is:

```sql
SELECT SYSUTCDATETIME() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time';
```

Though this could be abbreviated to:

```
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time';
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have check using SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() but it gives time zone with
> current datetime not UTC

Correct, `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` returns a `datetimeoffset` but with the current UTC offset of the database server. Specify `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` to get a `datetimeoffset` with the UTC time with a zero offset:

```
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

Comment: why in postgresql show "2022-12-02 13:02:48.941689+05:30", it should be "2022-12-02 13:33:33.8176409 +00:00" correct?

Comment: @Rchoudhary, I don't use PostgreSQL much but I would expect `now() at time zone 'utc'` to be equivalent to the SQL Server expression in my answer.  The only difference should be PostgreSQL `timestamp` as the result type instead of SQL Server `datetimeoffset` type. If the PostgreSQL isn't returning the value you expect, ask a new question with the PostgreSQL tag only.